# why glReadPixel GL_RGB from PBO got error 0x502 INVALD OPTION

Tags: opengl-es-3.0, pbo

I saw

> format specifies the format of the returned pixel values; accepted values are:
>
> GL_ALPHA
>   GL_RGB
>   GL_RGBA
>   RGBA color components are read from the color buffer. Each color component is converted to floating point such that zero intensity maps to 0.0 and full intensity maps to 1.0.
>
> Unneeded data is then discarded. For example, GL_ALPHA discards the red, green, and blue components, while GL_RGB discards only the alpha component. GL_LUMINANCE computes a single-component value as the sum of the red, green, and blue components, and GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA does the same, while keeping alpha as a second value. The final values are clamped to the range [0, 1]."

at https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glReadPixels.xml

It's work well if use GL_RGBA. But if I change

> glReadPixelsPBOJNI(0, 0, width, height, GLES30.GL_RGBA, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

to

> glReadPixelsPBOJNI(0, 0, width, height, GLES30.GL_RGB, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

0x502 is got. What's wrong with this?

My code is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347835/how-can-i-implement-pbopixel-buffer-object-in-android-grafika-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GL_RGB` is not generally supported as a format for `glReadPixels()` in OpenGL ES. From the ES 3.0 spec:

> Only two combinations of format and type are accepted in most cases. The ﬁrst varies depending on the format of the currently bound rendering surface. For normalized ﬁxed-point rendering surfaces, the combination format RGBA and type UNSIGNED_BYTE is accepted. [..]
>
> The second is an implementation-chosen format from among those deﬁned in table 3.2, excluding formats DEPTH_COMPONENT and DEPTH_STENCIL. The values of format and type for this format may be determined by calling GetIntegerv with the symbolic constants IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT and IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_TYPE, respectively.

So unless you query the implementation-chosen format, and it comes back as `GL_RGB`, you cannot use `GL_RGB`. The only format you can use everywhere is `GL_RGBA`.

The quote from the man page you found looks like a simple mistake. If you look at the top where the arguments are listed, it does not list `GL_RGB` as valid under *format*. So the information on that page is clearly inconsistent. Errors in the man pages are common. In case of doubt, you have to check the spec documents for more conclusive information.